# How did you learn and get interested in physics?

Tags: soft-question

I have lost interest in physics after being stuck in a hard problem. 
I asked a question here recently and a person responded with "You shouldn't be learning physics to solve textbook problems".

So my question not only being the question above but also what keeps you interested in learning physics?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  this is about physicists' personal motivations.

Comment: "**Physics**" is a name for "**how the World works**". What can motivate more than being able to explain *everything* you can point at around you? If your son asks "*Why can't we carry electricity in a cup?*" or your brother asks "*How come I can touch an $80\;\mathrm{^\circ C}$ wooden plank but are burned by an $80\;\mathrm{^\circ C}$ steel plate?*" or you father asks "*Why did the door just slam shut when I opened the living room window?*" or... The feeling of understanding the World and its mechanisms and phenomena can be an enormous driving factor.

Comment: For getting this on-topic, it may be appropriate to make it more general, about physicists' motivations in general, rather than a question soliciting personal responses.  I'm unclear about where the line for acceptable [tag:soft-question]s may be, though it seems plausible to me that this may be within the scope of SE.Physics.

Comment: Then, the alternative would seem to be [SE.Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/), again noting that a question should be less a solicitation of personal responses and more a question about the research community itself.

Comment: It's true this question is off-topic, but it's sad we have to reject such good questions. My advice is: "don't let anybody tell you how you should learn physics, he probably didn't even know you". You have to do it as you want to. I'm still learning physics, but I was interested because "they make the sense", they explain the word, and they add "order" to the world. They explain the why of things.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning my personal experience, it was the  unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics in the physical world. It happened when I was 8 or 9, when my father explained me that Einstein formulated the theory of relativity without making an experiment. Focussing on this interplay permitted me to learn both physics and mathematics and still is the principal motivation of my interest in both sciences.
(I know, the question is not pertinent to pse and an answer is not due, but I was not able to resist.)

Comment: And personally I was most interested by the results of experiments, like how a hammer and feather fall at the same speed on the moon. I wonder  if this is a good predictor of the field of physics one eventually goes into...